# Canvas Drawing: Await for images to load in a recursive method

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-canvas

I am implementing a recursive method that takes an array of images and draw them into a canvas:

```
async drawImages(ctx, images): Promise<any> {
    const img = images.shift();
    const imgToDraw = new Image();
    imgToDraw.src = img.src;
    imgToDraw.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(imgToDraw, img.x, img.y, img.w, img.h);
        if (images.length > 0) {
            this.drawImages(ctx, images);
        } else {
            console.log("I - Processing");
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the execution of this method, I need to retrieve the DataURL of the canvas, and I am doing it this way:

```
someCallingMethod() {
    //...
    await this.drawImages(ctx, images);
    console.log("II - Finished");
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that the await is not working on the `drawImages` method. When executing this code, I always get the `"II - Finished"` log before the `"I - Processing"` one, and therefore the `canvas.toDataURL()` never contains the images that are supposed to be drawn to the canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the Promise synchronously.
Here you are returning it in the asynchronous `onload` event handler.
So `drawImages` won't return a Promise but undefined.

Also, you will want to return the next iteration of `drawImages` everytime, so that your external `await` awaits for all of these Promises:

```js
const obj = {
  async drawImages(ctx, images) {
    // return a Promise synchronously
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const img = images.shift();
      const imgToDraw = new Image();
      imgToDraw.src = img.src;
      imgToDraw.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(imgToDraw, img.x, img.y, img.w, img.h);
        if (images.length > 0) {
          // resolve with next iteration so we can await all
          resolve(this.drawImages(ctx, images));
        } else {
          console.log("I - Processing");
          // done
          resolve();
        }
      };
      imgToDraw.onerror = reject;
    });
  }
};

(async () => {
  const images = [];
  // picsum.photos doesn't fill all the indexes...
  const urls = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "10", "11", "12", "13"];
  const s = 50; // image size
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    images.push( {
      src: `https://picsum.photos/${s}/${s}?image=10` + urls[i],
      x: (i%5)*s,
      y: Math.floor(i/5)*s,
      w: s,
      h: s
    });
  }
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  await obj.drawImages(ctx, images);
  // fill a green rect over to show we are able to await it
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0, 0.2)';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  console.log("all done");
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: in my case It sometimes starts again before previous one completely finishes. when I console log length images array in drawImages method  it goes like 6 5 5 4 3 3 3 2 1 1. So sometimes it draws some images double or triple times? Since it's a promise shouldn't it wait until resolve or there is another problem?

Comment: @OuzKagan very weird indeed, and I can't reproduce using the code in this answer, for me adding a `console.log(images.length)` correctly outputs 9-8-7-6...2-1. Are you sure you didn't change something else? Could you paste your code in a https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kaiido. I guess the problem I was I was calling below function inside a loop and when I made that loop with promise it fixed the issue.